# Transform data to growth rates in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two variables and I want to express one of them (monetary_base) in terms of monthly growth. 
How can I do that?. In the R language you should first transform the data into time series, in Python is this also the case?

```
#LLamando a las series que buscamos    
inflacion = llamada_api('https://api.estadisticasbcra.com/inflacion_mensual_oficial')
base_monetaria = llamada_api('https://api.estadisticasbcra.com/base')

#Armando DataFrames
df = pd.DataFrame(inflacion)
df_bm = pd.DataFrame(base_monetaria)

#Renombrando columnas
df = df.rename(columns={'d':'Fecha',
                        'v':'IPC'})

df_bm = df_bm.rename(columns={'d':'Fecha',
                              'v':'base_monetaria'})

#Arreglando tipo de datos
df['Fecha']=pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha'])
df_bm['Fecha']=pd.to_datetime(df_bm['Fecha'])

#Verificando que las fechas esten en formato date
df['Fecha'].dtype
df_bm['Fecha'].dtype

#Filtrando 
df_ipc = df[(df['Fecha'] > '2002-12-31')]
df_bm_filter = df_bm[(df_bm['Fecha'] > '2002-12-31')]

#Graficando
plt.figure(figsize=(14,12))
df_ipc.plot(x = 'Fecha', y = 'IPC')
plt.title('IPC-Mensual', fontdict={'fontsize':20})
plt.ylabel('IPC')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

The data looks like this

```
         Fecha  base_monetaria
1748 2003-01-02           29302
1749 2003-01-03           29360
1750 2003-01-06           29524
1751 2003-01-07           29867
1752 2003-01-08           29957
        ...             ...
5966 2020-02-18         1941302
5967 2020-02-19         1941904
5968 2020-02-20         1887975
5969 2020-02-21         1855477
5970 2020-02-26         1807042
```

The idea is to take the data for the last day of the month and calculate the growth rate with the data for the last day of the previous month.

Comment: Is the `base_monetaria` cumulative value for each month? You need to make sure the `Fecha` column is date time. You can do that using `df['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha'])`. Also set the datetime to index using `df.set_index('Fecha', inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solve creating a column with the lag values of base_monetaria

```
df_bm_filter['is_month_end'] = df_bm_filter['Fecha'].dt.is_month_end
df_last_date = df_bm_filter[df_bm_filter['is_month_end'] == True]
df_last_date['base_monetaria_lag'] = df_last_date['base_monetaria'].shift(1)
df_last_date['bm_growth'] = (df_last_date['base_monetaria'] - df_last_date['base_monetaria_lag']) / df_last_date['base_monetaria_lag']
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `base_moetaria` is a monthly cumulative value then

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Fecha': ['2020-01-31', '2020-02-29', '2020-03-31', '2020-05-31', '2020-04-30', '2020-07-31', '2020-06-30', '2020-08-31', '2020-09-30', '2020-10-31', '2020-11-30', '2020-12-31'],
                   'price': [32132, 54321, 3213121, 432123, 32132, 54321, 32132, 54321, 3213121, 432123, 32132, 54321]})

df['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha'])
df.set_index('Fecha', inplace=True)
new_df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M")).tail(1).reset_index()
new_df['rate'] = (new_df['price'] -new_df['price'].shift(1))/new_df['price'].shift(1)
```

The new_df['rate'] will give you the growth rate the way you explained in the comment below

Comment: It´s work but now how should I express the growth rates ?

Comment: what is the formula for growth rate? previous / current times 100?

Comment: (value in period t) - (value in period t-1) / (value in period t-1) or ln(value in period t)-ln(value in period t-1)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Fecha': ['2020-01-31', '2020-02-29', '2020-03-31', '2020-05-31', '2020-04-30', '2020-07-31', '2020-06-30', '2020-08-31', '2020-09-30', '2020-10-31', '2020-11-30', '2020-12-31'],
                   'price': ['32132', '54321', '3213121', '432123', '32132', '54321', '32132', '54321', '3213121', '432123', '32132', '54321']})

df['Fecha'] = df['Fecha'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df['is_month_end'] = df['Fecha'].dt.is_month_end
df = df[df['is_month_end'] == True]

df.sort_values('Fecha',inplace=True)

df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace = True)

def change(x,y):
    try:
        index = df[df['Fecha']==y].index.item()
        last = df.loc[index-1][1]
        return float(x)/float(last)
    except:
        return 0


df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda row: change(row['price'],row['Fecha']), axis=1)

df.head(12)
```

Comment: Did you change 'price' for 'base_monetaria'?, can you replace the except part with

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return 0

Comment: I  only changed price for base_monetaria